# Sort the new added items in a combobox alphabetically while ensuring that the matching items in a second combobox remain associated

Tags: c#

I have been trying to solve the problem described in the title for days without any success.

For the cbFunktion Combobox, it retrieves all the rows from the Funktionstabelle table using a SqlCommand, then loops through the SqlDataReader and adds each "Cat_Funktion" value to the combo box's Items collection. At the same time, it creates a new Funktionstabelle object and adds it to the funktionsTabelle list.

For the cbBlock Combobox, it retrieves all the rows from the Hilfstabelle table using a SqlCommand, then loops through the SqlDataReader and creates a new Hilfstabelle object for each row, adding it to the hilfsTabelle list.

The DataSource property of the combo boxes is then set to the appropriate list, and the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties are set to the appropriate column names ("Cat_Funktion" and "FBlock" respectively).

So after adding the new item to the funktionsTabelle list, i reset the data source of cbFunktion by setting it to null and then setting its DisplayMember, ValueMember, and DataSource properties. Finally, i update the selected value of cbFunktion to the new item's FT_ID.

Without sorting everything works fine, but the new added item in cbFunktion appears at the bottom of the list and is not sorted alphabetically. When i sort the item in cbFunktion alphabetically i am not able to sort the items in cbFunktion alphabetically and match the corresponding FBlock values in hilfsTabelle. One item in cbFunktion can have one or more items matching in cbBlock.

This is what i've tried without solving my problem:

```
private void UserControl1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Clear the combo boxes
            cbFunktion.Items.Clear();
            cbBlock.Items.Clear();


            // Load Funktion and Hilfstabelle into memory
            LoadFunktionsTabelle();
            LoadHilfsTabelle();

            // Sort functionNames using de-DE culture
            var functionNames = funktionsTabelle.Select(ft => ft.Cat_Funktion).ToList();
            //functionNames.Sort(new Comparer());
            functionNames = funktionsTabelle.Select(x => x.Cat_Funktion).ToList();
            functionNames = functionNames.OrderBy(x => x, new CultureComparer()).ToList();

            // Add sorted items to the combo box
            cbFunktion.Items.AddRange(functionNames.ToArray());
        }
        private void LoadFunktionsTabelle()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdFunk = new SqlCommand("Select * from Funktionstabelle", con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmdFunk.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                funktionsTabelle.Add(new Funktionstabelle()
                {
                    FT_ID = ((int)dr["FT_ID"]),
                    Cat_Funktion = dr["Cat_Funktion"] as string
                });
            }
            con.Close();
        }

        private void LoadHilfsTabelle()
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdBlock = new SqlCommand("Select * from Hilfstabelle", con);
            SqlDataReader dr1 = cmdBlock.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr1.Read())
            {
                hilfsTabelle.Add(new Hilfstabelle()
                {
                    H_ID = ((int)dr1["H_ID"]),
                    FBlock = dr1["Fblock"] as string,
                    HFT_ID = ((int)dr1["HFT_ID"])

                });
            }
            con.Close();
        }



        //Set the data source for cbBlock based on the selected item in cbFunktion
        private void cbFunktion_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (cbFunktion.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                cbBlock.DataSource = null; // clear the data source
                int id = funktionsTabelle[cbFunktion.SelectedIndex].FT_ID;
                cbBlock.DataSource = GetBlockById(id); // set the data source again
            }
            else
            {
                cbBlock.DataSource = null;
            }
        }

        private string[] GetBlockById(int id)
        {
            return hilfsTabelle.Where(line => line.HFT_ID == id).Select(l => l.FBlock).ToArray();
        }

        public class CultureComparer : IComparer<string>
        {
            public int Compare(string x, string y)
            {
                return CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.CompareInfo.Compare(x, y, CompareOptions.StringSort);
            }
        }
```

This creates a custom CultureComparer class that implements the IComparer interface, which allows us to use it as a parameter to the OrderBy method. The Compare method of the CultureComparer class uses the Compare method of the CompareInfo object of the CultureInfo object to compare the strings using the current culture's string sort order (CompareOptions.StringSort).

EDIT: Answer for @RatzMouze

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see the selected item in "Funktion" don't matches with the item in "Block", as you can see in the SQL Database. That happens only after sorting the items in the cbFunktion Combobox, as shown in my code.

Comment: Can you provide a picture of what your UI looks like? It sounds like a UI Design flaw that you are trying way to hard to get working.

Comment: @RatzMouze The 532 is the HFT_ID and 713 is the H_ID (Auto-Incrementing). The HFT_ID in Hilfstabelle matches with FT_ID in Funktionstabelle. As i already mentioned, as long i'm not sorting the new added item in cbFunktion Combobox everything works fine.

Comment: I dont know what any of those names and numbers mean, you have to explain it more clearly. Do you have all the "funktion" rows, loaded into the left combobox and the "hilfs"/"blocks" loaded into the right combobox, and then sort the combobox to the left?

Comment: @RatzMouze Yes, exactly. The "funktion" rows are loaded into the left combobox, and the "blocks" into the right combobox. One "funktion" can have 0,1 or more "blocks".

Comment: You want to create a select statement selecting all funktions and load them into the combobox. Then you want to create a "when combobox changed" event. When that event triggers, create a select statement selecting all blocks associated with the funktion, and then load them into the right combobox.